# Which directories does the Media Scanner scan?

Tags: media-search, media-scanner

Which directories does the Media Scanner scan at startup?

Is it only the sdcard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Media Scanner scans both SD card as well as USB storage, but not ROM and system storage. Means, it scans from `/sdcard/` and `/sdcard/external_sd/` mount points. It goes deep inside all non-hidden sub-directories, unless `.nomedia` file is detected.

Media Scanner skips ROM and system storage because both require root permission to write anything there. And, its very unlikely for an end-user to store music, photo there.

Comment: and except the hidden folders.

Comment: @roxan oh missed that.. thanks. added that in answer..

Comment: btw, would it be possible to make it search further dirs?

Comment: @MobileCushion Unable to understand what you're asking.. Plz, elaborate it. If you are concerned about `.nomedia`, it works as follows: When this file is found in a directory, all items (including sub-directories) of this directory are skipped.

Comment: If you don't want to create/manage .nomedia files by hand, use [Nomedia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.droida.nomedia) app.

Comment: I was asking if there is a way for the Media Scanner to search more dirs than just the ones you mentioned

Comment: @MobileCushion Why would you need this? What I have mentioned aren't directories. Those are mount points of storage devices. And, all of end-user files/directories can be located under it. So, both mount points cover overall file system usable to end-users!

Comment: @roxan Does this mean that if I put all my files in subdirectories of a hidden folder, they won't be analyzed by Media scanner? This would be cool for my purpose.

Comment: @Basj You're correct.

Comment: @MobileCushion I am using Musicolet player, and it gives you an option to use its own scanner or system scanner and you can choose which folders to scan and not to scan, also internal storage. I do not know, if it affect to what media files other apps see.